# How to sort with more than three columns?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

My worksheet has a large table with five columns. Row 1 has headers. I would like to sort the entire table using four column headers as sort fields.

VBA only allows three, so I tried the following

```
Sub CreateTimeSeries()

    With Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I get

> Run-time error '1004':
> Unable to get the Sort property of the Range class.

It can't be the worksheet. I select the worksheet before running the routine. Trying various solutions on StackOverflow has not fixed the error.

Comment: What Excel version?

Comment: Excel 365, the current version

Comment: Sorting `D1` before sorting the other columns is analogous to sorting all 4 fields together.

Comment: That can't be - that makes a single column sort all one ever needs. In this case it simply isn't true - column D has about 10 values, which column A has 80,000 names  and columns B and C have two relevant dates. Essentially, I'm sorting by date of birth, date of response, name and response.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
Sub CreateTimeSeries()

    Dim tbl As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set tbl = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    End With
    
    With tbl.Parent.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange tbl      '<<<<<<<
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It does indeed, but it sorts the entire sheet, not just the first 5 columns. I can get a similar result with
`    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
......
        .        .SetRange Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        .Apply
    End With`

Comment: If you have other content on the sheet then `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` will include that.  Maybe try `Set tbl = .Range("A1").Currentregion` instead

Comment: That does the trick. Thank you. I haven't seen the .Parent qualifier, and will look it up.